# monotouch ios - audioplayer returns nil when initializing

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Okay, I have this problem for almost a month now. Some audio files are not playing. It just returns an error like this:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer': the native 'initWithContentsOfURL:error:' method returned nil.

Here's the code initialising the AudioPlayer:

```
    NSData data = new NSData();
    if (AppSession.IsConnected ()) {/*Just a checker if connection is available or not*/
        if (uri != null && uri.ToString().Length > 0) {
            data = await LoadData (uri);
        }
    } else { data = null; }

    string saveFile = FolderPath(uri, "playthrough");
    data.Save(saveFile, false);
    NSUrl fileUrl = NSUrl.FromString(saveFile);
    audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(fileUrl);
    audioplayer.NumberOfLoops = 0;
    audioplayer.Volume = 1.5f;
    audioplayer.PrepareToPlay();
    audioplayer.Play();
```

For LoadData:

```
    public static async Task<NSData> LoadData (NSUrl url)
    {
        NSData data = new NSData ();
        if (url.ToString ().Contains ("http")) {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
            Task<byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (url.ToString ());
            var contents = await contentsTask;
            data = NSData.FromArray(contents);
        } else { data = NSData.FromUrl (url); }
        return data;
    }
```

For FolderPath:

```
    public static string FolderPath(NSUrl url, string fileName)
    {
        string[] dotSplitter = url.ToString ().Split (new char[]{ '.' }, 4);
        string ext = "";
        if (dotSplitter.Length == 4) {
            switch (dotSplitter [3]) {
            case "wav": ext = ".wav"; break;
            case "mp3": ext = ".mp3"; break;
            case "3gpp": ext = ".3gpp"; break;
            case "mp4": ext = ".mp4"; break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (dotSplitter [0]) {
            case "wav": ext = ".wav"; break;
            case "mp3": ext = ".mp3"; break;
            case "3gpp": ext = ".3gpp"; break;
            case "mp4": ext = ".mp4"; break;
            }
        }

        return Path.Combine(TMPDir(), fileName + ext);
    }
```

And here are the files I'm using to test the audio:

- http://files.parsetfss.com/6ea4a3c5-a4e2-463f-8374-247d5db0fbd5/tfss-c7db3001-b7b0-465d-b59b-233c1fe568ec-filtered_427201531308PM_song.wav
- http://files.parsetfss.com/6ea4a3c5-a4e2-463f-8374-247d5db0fbd5/tfss-c4426fba-ea52-4764-9fb6-6b9f10aba89f-filtered_27042015154318_song.wav

So, yeah. I've done dozens of research, google, experiment and tears for this, but I ended up with no result at all. Any solutions for this?

Comment: What error is returned by the initWithContentsOfURL method?

Comment: You mean the NSError? The error returns nothing. The code just stops on the line where AudioPlayer initialises.

Answer (score 2):

The full exception you should get is:

> System.Exception : Could not initialize an instance of the type 'MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer': the native 'initWithContentsOfURL:error:' method returned nil.
>   It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Following the above advice (use the overload accepting an `NSError`) and the one from the exception message you get something like:

```
MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure = false;
NSError error;
using (var url = NSUrl.FromString ("http://files.parsetfss.com/6ea4a3c5-a4e2-463f-8374-247d5db0fbd5/tfss-c7db3001-b7b0-465d-b59b-233c1fe568ec-filtered_427201531308PM_song.wav"))
using (var player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl (url, out error)) {
    Console.WriteLine (error);
}
```

You'll get:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

which is a very common error for `AVAudioPlayer`. I also get the same error if you use an `NSData` (local file). However `AVPlayer` loads the URL just fine...

Comment: What do you mean AVPlayer loads the URL just fine? Before using AVAudioPlayer, I used the AVAsset/AVPlayerItem/AVPlayer combo to stream the file and ended up with no luck. Please clarify.